# Can you install Xcode 4 on Snow Leopard Server without technical issues?

Tags: mac, installation, xcode, osx-server, snow-leopard-server

Simply put, is it possible to run Xcode on Snow Leopard Server? I want to know if there are any issues in doing so; not just in theory but with definitive answers.

I say that because half people I've ask just guess and say "Isn't SL Server just Snow Leopard with iLife taken out and 'server' stuff added in?" while others have said "That's not actually the case, as a lot of the libraries needed for client applications simply aren't there, plus the OS itself isn't properly tuned to support client applications."

And for those who say 'Just install it and see'... I don't know about you, but setting up a new OS is time-consuming.

And running Server virtualized isn't really helpful as

- There are known issues with virtualizing SLS depending on which you use, VMware, Parallels or VirtualBox,
- That just means I'd be doing TWO full installs of the OS and Xcode... Once virtualized, then again on the bare hardware.

Comment: The proper way to do [this](http://superuser.com/questions/291316/can-you-install-xcode-4-on-snow-leopard-server-without-technical-issues) would have been asking a moderator for help by e.g. flagging your closed question for attention.

Comment: @Daniel Beck, sorry, didn't see the 'flag' option.  I only knew about tagging specific posters so I flagged him after trying to see if I could PM him privately. I only found his personal e-mail or going via chats.  Thanks for pointing flagging out to me.  Very good to know. (BTW, the link in your post ('this') is dead so I don't know what you were trying to show me. (Also, your name has a space so I'm not even sure you're being tagged here.  Let me know.)

Comment: You don't have to move terabytes of data over to check that this is possible. Try to look for videos or tutorials of people using Snow Server to see if it looks the same, if it does then it does have all the client/gui libraries. The fact that they are merging Server and Client for Lion without anyone suggesting thats a change for Server suggests it looks the same, and only has the extra server programs.

Comment: I've used SLS before.  The GUI looks very similar.  But that doesn't tell you about all client libraries. For instance, having a library for UI items doesn't tell you if you have the same libraries for say, how data or networking is handled.  And routinely, server libraries even share a lot of functions with their client counterparts, but there are a lot of differences too.  Just look at the LDAP and MAPI libraries on Windows.  Same names, same basic functionality, but completely different security and permissions (not on the filesystem, I mean on capabilities of what they can access.)

Comment: I linked to your original topic that was deleted by a moderator in the meantime. @-notifications work with three or more characters matching the prefix of a name, so @Dan and @Daniel would both work (you actually used the former, as spaces are ignored). The *really* proper way to notify me would be @DanielBeck. Good luck with your question.

Comment: Also @tobylane, look at iPhone/iPod Touch compared to the new Nano 6G. They LOOK identical in form, function and gesturing usability, but they are a completely different OS underneath and it's a safe bet that Xcode doesn't just rely on the UI. (And I know that about Lion, but I'm asking about SLS specifically.)

Comment: as @DanielBeck mentions - use the flag option or post on [Meta](http://meta.superuser.com) to raise a complaint - don't use the questions sections for that.

Comment: @Sathya, that was already established above, but thanks.  Still curious about the ins and outs of user-tagging/notifications though.

Comment: @Marque - this [question](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2081/how-do-comment-replies-work/2082#2082) explains the details

Comment: Thanks @Sathya.  And thanks too for shortening my question. :)  I can be a tad loquacious.

Comment: @Marque You're quite welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There shouldn't be a problem. [Apple's Technical Specifications for Mac OS X Server](http://www.apple.com/server/macosx/specs.html) includes Xcode in it, thus guaranteeing that it will work.

Comment: Excellent find!  MAN... and it was right there in front of me all along!  I'm so used to downloading Xcode from the site to make sure I had the latest that I completely forgot Apple ships Xcode with/on the OS disks which tells you right there... no issue!  Thanks again!  [Phew!! I have a huge smile on my face knowing hours will not be wasted!]